# Ways of choosing k things from n in a straight line

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there of choosing $k$ things from $n$ in a line, one of the two ends is always chosen?

For example, consider $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ in a line. Let us choose $3$ numbers from them such that one of the two ends is always chosen($1$, $5$ are the ends in this case.). The total numbers of ways would be $\tbinom 5 3 - 1=9$.

How could I generalize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so let's look at the case where neither of the end points are chosen.  Then out of our original $n$ string, we now only have $n-2$ numbers and we have to fill $k$ spots.  But this is the complement of what we need, since the other options are both endpoints, or either endpoint.  So yes, you were right in your comment...

If the set of all combinations with no endpoints was $N$ and the set of all combinations was denoted $C$, the set of combinations with at least one endpoint is $C-N$.  The total combinations are $C(n,k)$ and we subtract $C(n-2,k)$

So the number of combinations that include at least one end is
$$C(n,k)-C(n-2,k)$$

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Wouldn't it be `C(n,k)-C(n-2,k)`?

Comment: I'm sorry. The question was framed badly. I've edited the question.

Comment: 5 doesn't need to show up it 1 shows up.

Comment: @WolframH: I've to select `k` numbers such that one of the two end ones are always chosen.

Comment: see my change...you find the complement set, that of which no end points show and subtract that from the universal set of all combinations.  I didnt' understand your quesiton, but you seemed to have known the answer right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

We can choose one end but not the other. There are $2\binom{n-2}{k-1}$ ways to do this.

Or else we can choose both ends. There are $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$ ways to do this. Add.